# How to download files using java and moving them to a directory?

Tags: java, download

I've looked around for some script or some tutorial for downloading file using Java, and then moving them to a different directory. I've seen a lot of questions similar to mine answered, but they all vary. Is there a definite way to do this? I currently learning Java and don't have enough experience make functioning script for this. Could anyone help?

Comment: By "download and moving" you mean downloading a file from the Internet to a given folder?

Comment: yes sorry, i didn't specify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally think this is the best way to download a file from the web.
When you download the file, it is stored in current running program, not on the hard drive, unless you specify it to.

```
            URL url;
            URLConnection con;
            DataInputStream dis; 
            FileOutputStream fos; 
            byte[] fileData;  
            try {
                url = new URL("http://website.com/file.pdf"); //File Location goes here
                con = url.openConnection(); // open the url connection.
                dis = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
                fileData = new byte[con.getContentLength()]; 
                for (int q = 0; q < fileData.length; q++) { 
                    fileData[q] = dis.readByte();
                }
                dis.close(); // close the data input stream
                fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/kfang/Documents/Download/file.pdf")); //FILE Save Location goes here
                fos.write(fileData);  // write out the file we want to save.
                fos.close(); // close the output stream writer
            }
            catch(Exception m) {
                System.out.println(m);
            }
```